# How can use IDbCommandTreeInterceptor

Tags: entity-framework

I want to intercept all database query to add filters based on authorization info.

I implement the IDbCommandTreeInterceptor interface, but i don't known how to modify the tree query.

For example, i have the ClassA:

```
public class ClassA {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And now, i try to intercept all querys to filter all id's < 2

```
interceptor.Result.Where(classa = classa.Id < 2)
```

Is my idea correct? Is the IDbCommandTreeInterceptor interface the proper way to do this?

I don't found information about this interface in Internet.

Thanks

Comment: There is an example here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417#fbid= (starts after a few minutes).

Answer (score 1):

See the example that EF team member Rowan Miller presented at TechEd 2014. His example was [SoftDeleteInterceptor (on GitHub)](https://github.com/rowanmiller/Demo-TechEd2014/blob/master/FakeEstate.ListingManager/Models/EFHelpers/SoftDeleteInterceptor.cs) that changes a DELETE to an UPDATE of an IsDeleted flag on the entity.